# C# Editing items of two lists with same references

Tags: c#, list, reference, pass-by-reference

I have a List of `myClass` objects (some elements are added before)

```
List<myClass> myClassList1;
```

Then I copy some of the elements in this list into another list

```
List<myClass> myClassList2 = new List<myClass>();
foreach (myClass obj in myClassList1)
{
  myClassList2.Add(obj);
}
```

This list is now sorted

```
myClassList2.sort();
```

And then I want to modify the first element in this sorted list

```
myClassList2[0].id++;
```

Problem: in the `myClassList2` this element is modified, but not in `myClassList1`.

I thought adding `myClass` objects to a list will add a reference to this object, so i can modify it in the list (this was the actual plan).

Comment: What is the definition of `myClass`? It's not really a struct is it? (Actually it can't be a struct, you'd get a compile error. But what is the definition anyway?)

Comment: Sorry I should have said: Your code *should* work. Can you post a compilable Console App example that doesn't work?

Comment: Silly question maybe, but if your `myClassList2` is sorted, that means the item at `myClassList2[0]` is (likely) not the same item as at `myClassList1[0]`. You're not comparing `myClassList2[0].id` and `myClassList1[0].id` are you?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Hmm I think you might have hit on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It does update myClassList1 as you expect. You might want to post your code. Here's my code that updates both lists.

```
    public class myClass
    {
        int _id;
        public myClass(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return _id;
            }
            set
            {
                _id = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void BuildList()
    {
        List<myClass> myClassList1 = new List<myClass>();
        myClassList1.Add(new myClass(8));
        myClassList1.Add(new myClass(4));
        myClassList1.Add(new myClass(10));
        myClassList1.Add(new myClass(1));   // This would become the first item when the list is sorted.
        myClassList1.Add(new myClass(30));

        List<myClass> myClassList2 = new List<myClass>();
        foreach (myClass obj in myClassList1)
        {
            myClassList2.Add(obj);
        }

        myClassList2.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.Id.CompareTo(s2.Id));  // Sort by Id.

        // Modify the first element in the second sorted list.
        myClass firstElementList2 = myClassList2[0];
        firstElementList2.Id++;
        int valueInList2 = firstElementList2.Id; // Get the id that is incremented

        // Find the same object in first list...
        myClass sameElementInList1 = myClassList1.Find(x => x.Id.Equals(valueInList2));
        int valueInList1 = sameElementInList1.Id;

        if (valueInList2== valueInList1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cheers!");
        }
    }
```

To test:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void SKTestMethod()
        {
            Class1 c1 = new Class1();
            c1.BuildList();
        }
```